# Rails 4 error "param is missing or the value is empty:" in create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I've looked at several tutorials, the ruby guides, and several stackoverflow questions. I tried first with simple_form and now the old fashioned way and can't figure out why the params aren't being passed.

Controller:

```
def new
  @topgem = Topgem.new
end

def create 
  @topgem = Topgem.new(topgem_params)

  if @topgem.save
    redirect_to @topgem
  else
    render 'new'
  end
```

...

```
 private
    def topgem_params
      params.require(:name).permit(:url, :description, :downloads, :last_updated)
    end
```

Model:

```
class Topgem < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :votes
  has_many :users, through: :votes

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true, :length => {
    :minimum =>2,
    :maximum =>50}

  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true 
  validates :downloads, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@topgem) do |f| %>


  <%= f.label :name %>:
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

  <%= f.label :url %>:
  <%= f.text_field :url %><br />

   <%= f.label :description %>:
  <%= f.text_field :description %><br />

   <%= f.label :downloads %>:
  <%= f.number_field :downloads %><br />


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The error I am getting:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /topgems
param is missing or the value is empty: name
```

here are select instance variables:

Instance Variables

```
@_action_has_layout 
true

@_routes    
nil

@_headers   
{"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}

@_status    
200

@_params    
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Gx/UwvcvWZYWAUHxWGYlUQB/PNNUniBpCjlM1WEHAm+luYl94Kky5Ae9Ur40YVtrN2ebEEX8C0G3Cewu/SJSow==", "topgem"=>{"name"=>"bfgf", "url"=>"dd", "description"=>"ff", "downloads"=>"343"}, "commit"=>"Create Topgem", "controller"=>"topgems", "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: use `params.require(:topgem).permit(:name, :url, :description, :downloads, :last_updated)`

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @On Freund .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have required `params[:name]`, but the actual params are `params[:topgem][:name]`.

Change your `topgem_params` method to

```
params.require(:topgem).
  permit(
    :name,
    :url,
    :description,
    :downloads,
    :last_updated
  )
```